# Google Maps marker title not showing all content

Tags: java, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore, google-maps-markers

When clicking on a marker on google maps in my application, the marker only shows the first part of the title, but then adds "..." and not showing the rest, even though there ain't that much text.

[image: screenshot of marker and title]

The code is as below (only took the necessary part:

```
...
...
String name = (String) hashmap.get("Name");
double rating = (double) hashmap.get("Rating");
String category = (String) hashmap.get("Category");

googlemap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(oldSpot).title(name + "\n rating: " + rating + "\n" + category))
....
....
```

I know that an option is to create and handle a infowindow(), but the above solution is much simpler and should be possible, I think.

Do anyone have an idea of what I can do (or why it cuts if off) - besides creating an "infowindow()-class", add further design, etc..

The "name" is simply t3 by the way. Rating is '1' and category is 10 chars long, so approx 15 chars all together.

And I use java and Firestore, for notice.

Comment: try remove  the \n  ...  marker title is single line . .  you could use content (and `<br/>`) instead of title  . otherwise  you could use custom infoWindow

Comment: allright - didn't know that the title is single line. My workaround so far is to have the title as .title and then add a .snippet. This gives 2 lines, instead of one, and I still manage to avoid the infoWindow-setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue may be that you are using the default info window which only supports a single line title. You would need to do some tricky things in order to get the second line or just set up a custom [info window](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/infowindows) so that you can get all the information you want in it without the window looking weird and be able to get the display however you want.